# Java EE - Can't connect to database via JDBC at IntelliJ

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I'm having problems trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database via JDBC in a Java EE web application. The same code that I'll show **works** on *Netbeans* and *Eclipse*, but not on IntelliJ.

My Java EE application have the following servlet:

```
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
writer.println("<html>");
writer.println("<body>");
writer.println("<h1>TEST H1</h1>");
writer.println("<ul>");
writer.println("<li>TESTE LI</li>");
writer.println("<p>" + ConexaoBD.getName() + "</p>");
writer.println("</ul>");
writer.println("</body>");
writer.println("</html>");
```

where I am making a link to a class named 'ConexaoBD', with a method getName() that returns a string from a database table (just to test).

Here's my method getName(). It works on a console app, but not on Java EE.

```
Connection con = null;
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Properties props = new Properties();
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/customers";
props.setProperty("user","postgres");
props.setProperty("password","pass");
props.setProperty("ssl","true");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from table limit 1");
return rs.getString(2);
```

Comment: can you post the complete stack trace please ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you connect to a database in a Java EE application.

Typically, you would have code that looks something like:

```
 public class SomeService {

      @Resource(name="java:global/jdbc/myDataSource")
      private DataSource ds;

      public String performSomeQuery(...) {

          try (Connection con = ds.getConnection();
               Statement st = con.createStatement()) {
              ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from table limit 1");
              return rs.getString(2);
          }

      }

 }
```

The DataSource with `name="java:global/jdbc/myDataSource"`is configured in your application server according to its documentation. This configuration will include the such things as the JDBC URL and authentication information.

Comment: I didn't know that! Thank you, and surely will try this on my project.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the error stack trace. Meanwhile  check if the driver jar is added in the classpath(Lib folder) appropriately .

Comment: Yes, it was something like this.
I already had the .jar on the external libraries folder, but i needed to have it on the WEB-INF -> lib folder, since my servlet wasn't recognizing the driver for my jdbc connection.
Its solved now.